# Pegando resources aninhados no controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, controller, resources

Boa noite, esse é meu primeiro post aqui, estou aprendendo a usar a ferramenta, desculpe se fiz algo de maneira errada. Mas aqui vai o problema...
Estou tentando fazer um clone do "Trello" em Rails para uma disciplina da faculdade. Basicamente eu tenho um nos models um **Projeto** que um usuário cria, dentro desse projeto, o usuário pode criar quadros, chamados de **Boards**, e por fim, dentro dos boards, ele pode criar **Stories/issues**. No momento, meu arquivo de rotas está da seguinte maneira.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# Root Route
 root to: 'home#index'

# Devise Routes
 devise_for :users

# User Routes
 authenticate :user do
   namespace :users do
     root to: 'dashboard#index'

  resources :projects do
    resources :boards do
      resources :stories
    end
  end

  end
 end
end
```

O que eu quero, é que a action show de um projeto no projects_controller, mostre seus quadros e dentro dos quadros suas estórias, algo parecido com isso...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu até consegui fazer isso usando VueJS, mas eu quero que essa parte seja feita apenas com Rails.
Pra conseguir isso, eu sei que preciso pegar as estórias de um quadro no projects_controller, e é aí que estou me perdendo.

Segue meu projects_controller.rb

```
class Users::ProjectsController < Users::BaseController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
    @boards = @project.boards.sorted
    #@stories = @boards.??? >this guy here that is causing the problem
  end

  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.new
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(projects_params)

    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Projeto criado com sucesso"
      redirect_to [:users, @project]
    else
      flash[:error] = "Falha na criaçao do projeto"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(projects_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Projeto atualizado com sucesso"
      redirect_to [:users, @project]
    else
      flash[:error] = "Falha na atualizaçao do projeto"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Projeto excluido com sucesso"
    redirect_to [:users, :projects]
  end

  private
  def set_project
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  end

  def projects_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Tanto no **boards_controller** quanto no **stories_controller**, quando a action create é chamada, o redirect manda pro show do **projects_controller**, e eu preciso nessa action, mostrar os quadros e as estórias. Os quadros eu consigo mostrar da maneira como esta sendo feito, meu problema é com as estórias mesmo, que não estou conseguindo pegar elas e mandar pra view.
Os relacionamentos estão ok, pois pelo console do rails eu consigo criar e acessar tranquilamente.

Alguem poderia me dar uma mão? Já perdi 2 dias com esse problema.

Comment: Perdão, sou novo aqui, achei que era meio global. O problema é o seguinte. Como pode ver nas minhas rotas, eu tenho 3 recursos aninhados. E eu preciso mostrar os boards e os stories na action show do meu projects_controller. Em teoria, preciso pegar todas as estórias de um determinado board que está dentro de um determinado project. Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar as estórias do board e jogar pra view.

Comment: @FelipeKosouski você pode [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/296071/edit) sua pergunta, faça também o [**Tour**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona o site.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer usar o accepts_nested_attributes_for :author

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

dentro do teu model Projeto

has_many boards
accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards